# create a facebook event android

Tags: android, events, facebook-graph-api

I did the following coding:

Inside onCreate() I wrote:

```
    Facebook fc = new Facebook("392736034134808");
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsuncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fc);
    mAsuncRunner.request("/me/events",new EventRequestListener());
```

My EventReqestListner class that is below onCreate() is like this:

```
     class EventRequestListener implements
com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener {


public void onComplete(final String response) throws JSONException{         

System.out.println("in oncomplete of friend request listner ....");
String Name= "test";
String Location= "test";
String Description= "desc";
JSONObject event = new JSONObject();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("method","events.create");
event.put("page_id",123454);
event.put("name",Name);
event.put("location",Location);
event.put("start_time", "2013-05-14T10:13:00");
event.put("end_time", "2013-05-15T10:20:00");
event.put("privacy_type", "OPEN");
bundle.putString("event_info",event.toString());

try {
    fc.request("POST", bundle);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Event Posted");
}
```

My problem is this, I do not get any errors, exceptions. Also I do net get the event created. I am very new to android, your help is really valuable.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle auth and login before you can request a user's events. This includes asking the user's permission to allow your app to retrieve events.

Currently your code instantiates a Facebook object. After this you need to authenticate and log the user in. Some resources to help you implement this are:

- A step-by-step tutorial on how to create a basic Android Facebook app with auth and login: [Android Facebook Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)
- The Hackbook example of github: [Hackbook app source code on github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples/Hackbook). The Hackbook includes lots of useful code examples for implementing FB functionality on an Android app. It comes with complete auth/login code.
- A walk-through on [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/#login) of the Hackbook.

Also, your RequestListener code is not done right. It's currently trying to post data to FB. It's normally used to parse data coming *from* FB. Have a look at the examples in the links above to see how to use a RequestListener.

Comment: Thank you very much!, I will go through them all..:)